# $(window).height() false value on iOS 5.1 PhoneGap 1.7 jquery mobile when launching the app in landscape mode

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

If if launch the application holding the iPhone in portrait mode, everything works fine even when i rotate the iPhone everything still working good.
But when i launch my app holding the iPhone in landscape mode this does not work good on my first rotation after landscape launch, it ruins my design completely.
This is the sequence of var viewport = $(window).height values:

Launching **Portrait**:

- Launch: $(window).height() = 460px / $(window).width() = 320px;
- Rotate Landscape left: $(window).height() = 300px / $(window).width() = 480px;
- Rotate to portrait: $(window).height() = 460px / $(window).width() = 320px;

..... So this is working fine

Launching **Landscape**:

- Launch landscape left: $(window).height() = 300px / $(window).width() = 480px;
- Rotate **portrait**: $(window).height() = 300px / $(window).width() = 480px;
  **This should be: $(window).height() = 460px / $(window).width() = 320px;**
- Rotate landscape left: $(window).height() = 460px / $(window).width() = 320px;
  **This should be: $(window).height() = 300px / $(window).width() = 480px;**
- Rotate **portrait**: $(window).height() = 300px / $(window).width() = 480px;
  **This should be: $(window).height() = 460px / $(window).width() = 320px;**
- Rotate landscape left: $(window).height() = 460px / $(window).width() = 320px;
  **This should be: $(window).height() = 300px / $(window).width() = 480px;**

..... So this is ruined completely because of the first rotate action that didn't changed its values and now portrait design is on landscape and vice-versa.

```
function onBodyLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        $(window).bind('orientationchange', function () {
            if ($.mobile.activePage.attr("id") == "FirstPage") {       
                window.setTimeout(function () {

                    alert($(window).height() + " " + $(window).width());

                }, 250);
            }
        });
}
```

Thank you for helping but please note that the same code is working very good on android devices.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap is on version 2.2 now. Upgrade to the latest version, which includes many fixes for rotation and orientation. See [the phonegap website](http://phonegap.com/download) for more information.

Comment: I can't do that since xcode 4.5 is required to work with Phonegap 2.2. I am using xcode 4.3.3. I need a faster solution.

Comment: The problem is that i am using TabBar plugin and initializing it on device ready event. Is there anywhere else i can initialize my plugins without falling into problems on 1.7. I tried newer phonegap versions but it didn't worked. It just works when i remove my tabbar plugin.