# Google Analytics Plugin is not working with PhoneGap 2.1

Tags: cordova

I have upgraded my phonegap version to 2.1 and lot of errors are showing.
On the github there is no section talking about google analytics for 2.1.
[GitHub](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS)

Any idea about how to make them work together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for iOS I recently put together [this](https://github.com/jelled/google-analytics-cordova-ios) Git of the plugin code I used to get the latest Google Analytics working with Cordova 2.2.0. Note that the latest Google Analytics SDK uses different frameworks (SystemConfiguration and CoreData rather then libsqlite3.0.dylib) so if you are upgrading don't forget to swap those out.

If this is Android, although I haven't tested them out myself these two Gits purport to work on the latest version of Cordova on Android.

https://github.com/DoersGuild/Cordova-Android-Analytics

https://github.com/Ranhiru/cordova-google-analytics/tree/master/Android

Comment: Just want to add that another git repo worth checking out.  It seems to be more active.  https://github.com/DoersGuild/Cordova-Android-Analytics

Answer (score 0):

in the [README](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iOS/GoogleAnalytics/README.md), it said:

> Make sure you are running Cordova(PhoneGap) 1.5.0

In short, the plugin does not support PhoneGap 2.1 .

Comment: Yes you're right, but the problem that i have already a problem of rotation when using older phonegap versions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973733/window-height-false-value-on-ios-5-1-phonegap-1-7-jquery-mobile-when-launch/13974163#13974163
and it worked with 2.1 and now i'm stuck with google analytics problem. So i want a phonegap version that works with my two problems. And now im trying 1.9. Thank you